# why the shape drawable don't work for setBackgroundResource(), but the png drawable do?

Tags: android

When setBackgroundResource, the xml shape drawable don't work,but a png drawable do.
I use it in a ListView Adapter's getView():

```
        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(ctx);
        rl.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(300, 100));
        rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.curve_shap);//no effect
//rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);//png drawable,works well
        return rl;
```

the `/res/drawable/curve_shap.xml`
(it works well for background of RelativeLayout on a static xml Layout file)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFF0000" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#ffffffff" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: if you use normal `RelativeLayout` (instead of CustomView that extends RelativeLayout), does it work?

Comment: Where you have put your xml file?

Comment: @ pskink : yes,it work. if i set the shape background for a RelativeLayout  at a static XML layout file

Comment: @BBdev : res/drawable/

Comment: i got it, the "curve_shap.xml" is misstyped as "curve_shap.XML"